# Is there a way to have a single point feature with multiple records?

Tags: point, database-design

Is there a way to have a **single point feature** and have **multiple** <del>attributes</del> **records**  associated with it? Multipoint approach won't work as it gives me one attribute set (database row). I am trying to avoid having to stack points. Maybe my approach is flawed since I'm failing to find any relevant hits on a web search.

**Use case**: Access all details of personnel at company via a '*company building polygon centroid*' for instance, by simply clicking on the point feature.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming ArcGIS Desktop ... Use relates in the map or relationship classes in the geodatabase.

From the ArcGIS Desktop 10 help files with my emphasis below:

"Unlike joining tables, relating tables simply defines a relationship between two tables. The associated data isn't appended to the layer's attribute table like it is with a join. Instead, you can access the related data when you work with the layer's attributes.

**For example, if you select a building, you can find all the tenants that occupy that building.** Similarly, if you select a tenant, you can find what building it resides in (or several buildings, in the case of a chain of stores in multiple shopping centers—a many-to-many relationship). However, if you performed a join on such data, ArcMap will only find the first tenant belonging to each building, ignoring additional tenants."

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_joining_and_relating_tables/005s0000002n000000/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My working platform is indeed ArcGIS. Will keep this in mind. I am however looking at webmapping i.e. delivering the point data from a datatype (within GeoServer) that supports this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Please state what platform you are working with. If you are working with ArcGIS, I think you want to use relationship classes, which are tables which define a connectivity between feature points of different layers ( such as a company point layer and a table holding all employees). Holding them all in a single huge layer isn't practical.

Comment: ArcGIS for data management but ultimately I intend to deliver the data (Geoserver hosted) via an interactive web-map (openlayers) that supports this connectivity.